# Неверное количество строк в курсоре?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Почему эта процедура возвращает 2 строки вместо одной?

```
    declare
        type rc is ref cursor;
        tbl_dat rc;
        type dat_rec is record(id integer);
        dat dat_rec;
    begin
        open tbl_dat for 'select 1 id from dual';
        loop
            exit when tbl_dat%notfound;
            fetch tbl_dat into dat;
            dbms_output.put_line(dat.id);
        end loop;
    close tbl_dat; 
end;
```

И как ее построить, чтобы избежать повторения строки?

Comment: потому что вы проверяете `tbl_dat%notfound` до того как сделали fetch. А notfound будет установлен только _после_ того, как очередной fetch ничего не нашел

Comment: Понятно, Mike, спасибо